# How do I disable hover effect for a particular element inside a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to create this hover effect:

[image: normal state]

[image: hovering over the white part]

[image: hovering over the button]

Basically, stop the white part from darkening when a particular element from its child elements is being hovered on.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<div className= {css.searchBarDiv}>
  <div className={css.searchBarContent}/>
  <div className={css.searchBarButton}>
       <div className={css.button}>
           <Image/>
       </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's my attempt at the CSS code:

```
.searchBarDiv {

  &:hover {
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
  }
  &:focus-within {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: rgb(0 0 0 / 20%) 0px 6px 20px;
  }
}

.searchBarButton {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin-left: -6px;
  padding-right: 9px;
  align-self: center;
}
.button {
  max-width: 200px;
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
  background-color: #ee3465;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;

  &:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #df3562;
  }
}
```

Comment: try removing the  &:hover from .searchBarDiv

Comment: Can you just assign the hover effect to .searchBarContent instead of the parent? I'm assuming that the input field is inside the .searchBarContent element. And the round button is a sibling.

Comment: I can't find that which language it is .Please tell the `css` pre processer and html preprocesser

Comment: and also change css to scss ,less or  something that you are using

Comment: @Musafiroon its just done in REACT, class instead of className would make it work for regular code.

Answer (score 0):

Use custom CSS classes for those childs to have hover in them.

```
.searchBarDiv {
   .customClass{
       &:hover{ //bla bla bla}
   }
}
```

Comment: How can I use this in HTML? How do I define the classNames?

Answer (score 0):

As per you need, you need the hover effect of in the background which should not cover over the button. so what i would recommend is moving the hover property from .searchBarDiv to .searchBarContent. and for the button make it position absolute and increase the z-index of button as it will not get affected by the hover change in .searchBarContent. use searchBarDiv as only a wrapper of the custom search field you are creating.

Comment: alright in that case u can see the update answer.

Comment: What I mean is, I want the div to not get shaded when I am hovering over the button. This is happening because the button is in the same div, but I can't take it out of that div.

Comment: if you dont want button to be shaded when then apply the background color change on hover to searchBarContent instead of searchBarDiv

Comment: But I want the shading around the button like shown in the picture while hovering over the div. Just not when we are hovering over the button. I hope I am able to explain my problem, thank you for taking out time to help me.

Answer (score 0):

use classnames package or clsx to combine your classes for better ux. It is widely accepted solution. If your project does not permit to use extra packages try to condition you classes however you feel like either functions or inline conditionals to choose correct classes when some state on hover is true. on a cheerful note listen to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0yXJ4t6Ax1U