# How do I change an element's css while hovering over an element which lies after it?

Tags: html, css

I want to change the opacity of .dividor to 0 while hovering over any of the other divs. I don't know how to do this for the .secondDiv. I am just learning CSS.

HTML:

```
<div class="base">
   <div class="FirstDiv"></div>
   <div class="Dividor"></div>
   <div class="SecondDiv"></div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.base > div:hover + div {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the hover to the parent element

```css
.base:hover > div.Dividor {
 opacity: .1;
}
```

```html
<div class="base">
   <div class="FirstDiv">Hello World 1</div>
   <div class="Dividor"> Dividor</div>
   <div class="SecondDiv">Hello World 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, can you help me with one more problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69513478/how-do-i-disable-hover-effect-for-a-particular-element-inside-a-div